# Override javascript css

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to delete some elements on an external javascript. (LOGO and Upcoming events title).

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.bookyou.com/whitelabel/gigguide.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">BY.gigguide.show({ account:3734,item:27734,width:800,height:400 });< /script>
```

and I tried to add this line but it doesnt work:

```
<style type="text/css">#gigguide .gg-kop{ display: block !important; } < /style>
```

Comment: Please add some Code, and the created HTML-Snippet from the `BY.gigguide.show()`.

Comment: What are the styles you don't want from the js file? Add them to your question. Also add your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to style an element within an iframe. So you could do something like this:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("element-selector").css("display", "block");
```